# Passing variable from one iMacros to another?

Tags: imacros

I want to create a script, where the users inputs in the beginning something, and this variable input should be used for the rest of the loop (without asking for input again).
The best way i could come up with was to create two iMacros, one which asks for the input, and the other one who uses the input and loops it.
The major problem is, i can't save the input in Downloads/Datasource because the same iMacros should be used with other firefox instances. Which means, if the user inputs **A** on the first instance and on the next **B** then after the second loop of both all instances are using the varaible B. And i can't make multiple scripts since the user should have the ability to use unlimited times this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save easy the input in ‘Downloads/Datasource’. However make your second macro read this input only once:

```
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE inputs.csv
SET input EVAL("('{{!LOOP}}' == 1) ? '{{!COL1}}' : '{{input}}';")

' your further code here '
```

Comment: Thanks, had the issue, that i used {{!input}} as variable and not {{input}}